# Case Commands in script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, case

please find my script below :

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Will able to see the percentage of hard disk"
for line in $(cat /home/fk60/gerscript/systemlist/pre-prod.txt)
do
usage=$(ssh $line "df -P |grep '/opt/splunk'" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'

echo "Machine name: $( echo $line | cut -d'@' -f2 ) "
    case $usage in
         50 ) echo "when the hard disk is above 50%"
         echo "within limits"
            sudo /home/fk3/scripts/remove_old_data.sh 2880
            ;;
         [5-6][0-9]|7[0-5] ) echo "when the hard disk space is above 50%-75%"
          echo "out of limits"
            sudo /home/fk3/scripts/remove_old_data.sh 1440
            ;;
         7[6-9]|8[0-9]|90 ) echo "when the hard disk space is above 75%-90%"
            sudo /home/fk3/scripts/remove_old_data.sh 720
            ;;
         9[1-9]|100 ) echo "when the hard disk space above 91%"
           sudo  /home/fk3/scripts/remove_old_data.sh 360
            ;;
          * ) echo "Disk space is less than 50%"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

please find the output also :

output

```
Will able to see the percentage of hard disk
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Machine name: pd01.abc.com
Disk space is less than 50%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Machine name: pd02.abc.com
Disk space is less than 50%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Machine name: pd04.abc.com
when the hard disk space is above 50%-75%
out of limits
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Machine name: pd05.abc.com
Disk space is less than 50%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Machine name: pd09.abc.com
Disk space is less than 50%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i am unable to get the percentage of the server and unable to run the second script which will delete the data accordingly to the numbers(2880, 1440, 720, 360) if the second script also i fend the same percentage

Comment: It would be useful to see a [mcve] with sample input, but my immediate feeling is that you should just drop the case statement altogether, and parse the input with awk, something like `sudo /home/fk3/scripts/remove_old_data.sh "$(awk ...)"`, where the output of awk determines the argument to the script.

Comment: Since you're using `sudo` and this script looks like it deletes things, it would be safer to save the value in a variable `limit=$(awk ...)` and then do some validation before proceeding.

Comment: Please show us sample input and expected output more clearly so that we could try to help you on same.